# Sum multiuple columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have numbers stored in my MySQL (`paid`). I need to SUM the columns.

```
$sql= "SELECT SUM(furniture) FROM paid"; 
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$furniture = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn();

$sql= "SELECT SUM(groceries) FROM paid"; 
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$groceries = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn();

//so on....
```

There are morthan 50 columns in the database. My question is, Is there a shorter way to write this so I can get the SUM for each column and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Are you not able to execute one statement ("SELECT SUM(groceries), SUM(furniture) FROM paid") and then fetch the results as an array?

Comment: @MyCah Thanks your suggestion. Looks good but how can I assign each value in to a variable? Or should I do `SUM(groceries) AS groceries, ....`

Comment: I would say you should just add it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try with single query

```
$sql = "SELECT  SUM(`furniture`) AS sumFurniture, 
                SUM(`groceries`) AS sumGroceries ,
                ...
        FROM `paid` ";
```

result can be get with

```
$sth = $connect->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();

$sumFurniture = $result['sumFurniture'];
$sumGroceries = $result['sumGroceries'];
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them as a Single SQL Query

```
SELECT SUM(furniture) AS furniture, SUM(groceries) AS groceries....... FROM paid
```

Answer (score -1):

If your `where` clause is same you can combine the query like this:

```
 select sum(<column_name1>) column_name1,sum(<column_name2>) column_name2 from tablename where <where>
```

From php, you can fetch it: using array index "column_name1","column_name2"